# Lock Folder Using Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

How can we lock folder using Command Prompt, without setting the user permissions and without using the `attrib` command either.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be programming related. Try http://superuser.com/.

Comment: What do you mean by lock? Do you mean stop people from deleting, or stop people from opening without a password?

Answer (score 0):

First goto the folder directory and then type cacls folder_name /e /p everyone:n to lock and 
cacls folder_name /e /p everyone:f to unlock.

Comment: this is nothing but setting the user permissions.. My requirement is that i need using a password protected scheme.. anyways thanks for the reply